# Randomly occurring error (48, error loading DLL) when trying to send an email from access 2013 through outlook 2013

Tags: ms-access, outlook, vba

I am currently working on an access 2013 database. On one of the forms I have a button that collects information, then puts it into an outlook 2013 email and sends it. the code itself works, but sometimes (i can't predict when) I get an error that reads ["run-time error '48', Error loading DLL"](https://i.stack.imgur.com/92wE2.png). Once this happens i have to restart the computer in order to get the button working again.  I have only been working with VBA for a few weeks and have not had any luck finding out a way to fix this.

-the computers this program (it is a split database) is on have both office 2010 and 2013 on them . i don't know if this is causing the issue, but i don't know enough about what happens when they are on the pc at the same time to rule it out.

-this issue happens on both .accde and .accdb versions of the program

[here is what the debugger shows when the error happens](https://i.stack.imgur.com/DBNmI.png)

```
'below is the code for the button that sends the email
Public Sub Command239_Click()

Dim oApp As Outlook.Application
Dim oMail As MailItem
Dim db As Database

'there is code a bunch of code between here that does not 
'relate to sending the email

    'accessing outlook
Set oApp = CreateObject("Outlook.application")
Set oMail = oApp.CreateItem(olMailItem)      ' <<<<<<<<<<< this line is highlighted in yellow    >>>>>>>>>>>>>>       

'this is for the body of the email.
'things in quotes are text
'& between variables text and newlines
'type the variable to write its value
'vbCrLF goes to the next line
oMail.Body = "Incident Log: " & clsORopen & ", " & Lgst & ", " & Tme & vbCrLf & Division & ": " & Location & ", " & secLocation & vbCrLf & "Circuit/Apparatus: " & Circuit & vbCrLf & "Caused by: " & cause & ", " & rtcause & vbCrLf & vbCrLf & Disturbance & vbCrLf & vbCrLf & "Person Notified: " & Notified & vbCrLf & "Returned to Normal: " & Returned & vbCrLf & "User: " & getusername & " Date: " & Format(Now, "MMM,d,yyyy")

'the subject
oMail.Subject = Division & " - " & Tyype & ", " & Circuit

'sending to these people
oMail.To = emaillist
oMail.Send
Set oMail = Nothing
Set oApp = Nothing
```

Answer (score 0):

Seems like an issue on 64-bit Windows with 32-bit Office. One suggested solution:
http://support.mccpilotlog.net/support/solutions/articles/9864-windows-pc-run-time-error-48-error-loading-dll

More info here:
https://www.experts-exchange.com/questions/29012275/MS-Access-Run-time-error-48-Error-Loading-dll-after-upgrading-from-2013-64-bit-to-2016.html